# Shortest Username Available

Tags: python

I want to write a program in python that can find the shortest available username for example on Gmail.

I want to start from `"aaaaaa"` and end in `"zzzzzz"` and I want be able to check that in any website.

This is a library I find I am not sure if it's related to what I am looking for.

https://pypi.org/project/shortuuid/

I would appreciate if you can help with the topic I need to study or where to start.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `permutations` from the built-in `itertools` module:

```
from itertools import permutations

num = 6
chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"

for name in permutations(chars, num):
    print(''.join(name))
```

Explanation:

1. First, import `permutations` from `itertools`, obviously.

```
from itertools import permutations
```

2. Define two variables, one to store the minimum number of characters a username can contain, and the other to store all valid characters for a username.

```
num = 6
chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
```

3. Use a `for` loop to iterate through all the permutations of the previously defined valid characters with the previously defined length.

```
for name in permutations(chars, num):
```

4. Each permutation of the `for` loop will be a tuple, so to convert them into strings, use the `str.join()` method. Finally, print out the result.

```
    print(''.join(name))
```

Answer (score 2):

The primary property of UUIDs is that they are practically unique, but not necessarily that they are the shortest possible.

If you start at 'aaaaaa' and end at 'zzzzzz' it is likely the shortest username you will find will be 6 characters long.

If you just want to generate short random user names try the following with caution as it generates every combination of every available character:

```
from random import choice
from itertools import permutations

def character_permutations(min: int = 2, max: int = 4)
    chars = list('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz') + [str(x) for x in range(10)]
    return [''.join(x) for y in range(2,6) for x in permutations(chars, y)]



def character_permutations_gen(min: int = 2, max: int = 4):
    chars = list('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz') + [str(x) for x in range(10)]
    for y in range(2,6):
        for x in permutations(chars, y):
            yield ''.join(x)
            
usernames = character_permutations()
```

This might a difficult solution to confirm if you need the correct answer to be confirmed by Google's Gmail services which might be rate limited and may not allow you to just randomly lookup available usernames.